# javascript interactive stack which can push and pop using browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make an interactive stack application using javascript in browser but I cannot clear my console after every actions.

```
 <script>
        var st1 = 10;
        var stk1 = new Array(10);
        var count = 0;

        function push1(v) {
            if (st1 === 0) {
                rpiseconsole.log("Stack Overflow");
            }

            else {
                st1 = st1 - 1;
                stk1[st1] = v;

                print1();
            }
        }

        function pop1() {
            var temp = stk1[st1];

            st1 = st1 + 1;
            print1();
            return temp;
        }

        function print1() {
            for (var i = st1; i < 10; i++) {
                rpiseconsole.log(stk1[i]);
            }
        };

        function doJob() {
            var x = document.getElementById("t").value;

            push1(x);
            document.getElementById("t").value = "";
        }

        function doJob1() {
            var p = pop1();
            document.getElementById("t1").value = p;
        }
</script>
```

I am expecting that every time I click on the push button it will print the array of stack and clear the previous results in the console and when I click on the pop button it will take out the last data and print the remaining array into the textarea.

I cannot get the clear option in console and I cannot output my array to the textarea in the same order as I put items into the stack.

Comment: use console.clear()

Comment: console.clear() is clearing whole console any will not giving me any output

Comment: use it at the start of the function so it clear the previous result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a method `clearConsole()` and invoke it before every `print` command

```
function clearConsole() {
  document.getElementById( "rpiseconsole" ).innerHTML = "";
}
```

**Demo**

```js
var st1 = 10;
var stk1 = new Array(10);
var count = 0;

function push1(v) {
  if (st1 === 0) {
    rpiseconsole.log("Stack Overflow");
  } else {
    st1 = st1 - 1;
    stk1[st1] = v;
    print1();
  }
}

function pop1() {

  var temp = stk1[st1];

  st1 = st1 + 1;
  print1();
  return temp;


}

function print1() {
  clearConsole();
  for (var i = st1; i < 10; i++) {
    rpiseconsole.log(stk1[i]);
  }
};

function doJob() {
  var x = document.getElementById("t").value;
  push1(x);
  document.getElementById("t").value = "";
}

function doJob1() {
  var p = pop1();
  document.getElementById("t1").value = p;
}

function clearConsole() {
  document.getElementById( "rpiseconsole" ).innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>Procedural Stack with Tight Coupling</div>
<div id="rpisesetup">

  <textarea id="rpiseconsole"></textarea>
  <script src="https://sites.google.com/a/rajeshpatkar.com/library/hub/rpiseconsole.js">
  </script>
  <textarea id="t"></textarea>
  <textarea id="t1"></textarea>
  <button onclick="doJob()">push</button>
  <button onclick="doJob1()">pop</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please accept and upvote the answer that has helped you.

Comment: i do have one question.if i use constructor method can i make something interactive like user can choose from stack s1 or stack s2?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your question. Can you post a new question with expected output and relevant code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47660858/interactive-stack-using-checkbox-s1-and-s2-and-different-functions