# interactive stack using checkbox s1 and s2 and different functions

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am trying to make working model of Stack in which user can select the stack s1 or s2 and can perform operations like push and pop.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Stack With Constructor </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div>
            
            
            <p id="p1">
                stack
            </p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="stack1" value="s1">s1
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="stack2" value="s2">s2
            <br>
            <textarea id="tdisplay"></textarea>
            <textarea id="tpush"></textarea>
            <button onclick="doJob()">push</button>
            
            <button onclick="doJob1()">pop</button>
            <textarea id="tpop"></textarea>
        </div>
        
        <script>
             function myfunction() {
        if (document.getElementById("stack1").checked == true) {
            console.log('myFunction called!');
            s1 = new MyStack();
        }
        if (document.getElementById("stack2").checked == true) {
            s2 = new MyStack();
        }
    }
            function push(v) {
                if (this.st === 0) {
                    console.log("Stack Overflow");
                } else {
                    this.st = this.st - 1;
                    this.stk[this.st] = v;
                    document.getElementById("tdisplay").value=this.print();
                }
            }

            function pop() {
                if (this.st === 10) {
                    console.log("Stack Underflow");
                } else {
                    var temp = this.stk[this.st];
                    this.st = this.st + 1;
                    document.getElementById("tdisplay").value=this.print();  
                    return temp;
                }
            }

            function print() {
                console.log("Printing Stack");
                var str = "";//empty string
                for (var i = this.st ; i < 10; i++) {
                    console.log(this.stk[i]);
                    str+=this.stk[i]+'\n';//concatenate the value and a new line
                }
                return str;
            };

            function MyStack() {
                this.st = 10;
                this.stk = new Array(10);
                this.push = push;
                this.pop = pop;
                this.print = print;
            };

            var s1 = new MyStack();

            function doJob() {
                var x=document.getElementById("tpush").value;
                s1.push(x);
                
                document.getElementById("tpush").value="";
            }
            function doJob1(){
                var y=s1.pop();

                document.getElementById("tpop").value=y;
                              
            }
        </script>
    </body>
```

I don't know how to use checkbox method. It means when i select s1 checkbox it should create s1 stack and I can do operations on it and same as for s2.

The result should be proper browser functions for interactive stack so it can work like in following steps:

User select s1 or s2 stack
If he/she selects s1 then they can work for all operations for s1.
User can switch between s2 too and can perform all operations.
I am having issues on the checkbox working.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could have more luck with radio buttons. If s1 and s2 were a radio button group, like

  `<input type="radio" name="stack_select" id="stack1" value="s1">s1
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="stack_select" id="stack2" value="s2">s2`

Then you can listen to when either changes in one function, and have the other ui components update the proper, selected stack.

The problem with checkboxes for your case is that they aren't mutually exclusive, and it seems like you never want to have both s1 and s2 selected at the same time.